# Extracting every pixel value from matrix and storing it in new one in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, pixel

My problem is a typical newbie problem, I guess. 
My matrix looks as follows:

```
[102 183 301]
```

where the first and second dimensions are rows and columns and the third is the number of images I have to process. I am supposed to write a code to extract the pixel values for every pixel in every one of those 301 images and store it into a new matrix. 
I managed with only one pixel, my code looks as follows:

```
for y=1:301;
    inVal=squeeze(Data2(y,21,153));
    if y==1
        MAT=zeros(size(Data,3),size(inVal,1));
    end
    MAT(y)=squeeze(MAT(y,:))+inVal;
end
```

I previously permuted the matrix to get the pixel value out of every single image, but this does not work to find all the others or at least I wasn't able.
I would really appreciate some advise as I have never coded in my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the vector of all values of pixels at location (x,y) over all images, respecting your initial data layer, just do the following:

```
MAT = squeeze(Data(x,y,:));
```

Comment: What I needed was a little different: for X=1:x for Y=1:y if X==1 && Y==1 mat=zeros(size(th,1),size(th,2)); end if th(X,Y)>=lim1 && th(X,Y)<=lim2 mat(X,Y)=th(X,Y); end if th(X,Y)<=lim1 && th(X,Y)>=lim2 mat(X,Y)=0; end end end x describes length, y image width. Additionally I added 2 limits to sort the pixel values into. I did not specify my question too well, so your answer works though.